# Sum and product of Cardinal numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define the sum and the product of two cardinal numbers and show that these are well-defined operations.

That's what I have tried:

Let $A,B$ sets with $A \cap B=\varnothing, card(A)=m, card(B)=n$.

We define the sum $m+n$ of the cardinal numbers $m,n$ as the cardinal number of the union of $A$ and $B$, i.e.

$$m+n=card(A \cup B)$$

We will show that the sum of two cardinal numbers is well-defined.

It suffices to show that if $A_1 \sim B_1, A_2 \sim B_2$ with $A_1 \cap A_2=\varnothing, B_1 \cap B_2=\varnothing$ then $A_1 \cup A_2 \sim B_1 \cup B_2$.

We know that there are bijective functions $f: A_1 \to A_2, g:B_1 \to B_2$.

We want to show that there is a bijective function $h: A_1 \cup A_2 \to B_1 \cup B_2$.

We set $ h(x)=f(x)$ if $x \in A_1, h(x)=g(x)$ if $x \in A_2$.

We will show  that $h$ is 1-1.

Let $x_1, x_2 \in A_1 \cup A_2$ with $h(x_1)=h(x_2)$.

If $x_1, x_2 \in A_1$ then $h(x_1)=f(x_1), h(x_2)=f(x_2)$ and so $f(x_1)=f(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1=x_2$

If $x_1, x_2 \in A_2$ then $h(x_1)=g(x_1), h(x_2)=g(x_2)$ and so $g(x_1)=g(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1=x_2$ since $g$ is injective.

If $x_1 \in A_1, x_2 \in A_2$ then $h(x_1)=h(x_2) \Rightarrow f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ that cannot be true because $B_1 \cap B_2=\varnothing$.

We will show that $h$ is surjective, i.e. that $\forall y \in B_1 \cup B_2, \exists x \in A_1 \cup B_2$ such that $f(x)=y$.

If $y \in B_1$ then we know that there will be a $x \in A_1$ such that $h(x)=y \Rightarrow f(x)=y$ since $f$ is surjective.

If $y \in B_2$ then we know that there will be a $x \in A_2$ such that $h(x)=y \Rightarrow g(x)=y$ since $g$ is surjective.

We define the product $m \cdot n$ of the cardinal numbers $m,n$ as the cardinal number of the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$, i.e.

$$m \cdot n=card(A \times B)$$

We will show that the product of two cardinal numbers is well-defined.

It suffices to show that if $A_1 \sim B_1, A_2 \sim B_2$ with $A_1 \cap A_2=\varnothing, B_1 \cap B_2=\varnothing$ then $A_1 \times A_2 \sim B_1 \times B_2$.

We know that there are bijective functions $f: A_1 \to A_2, g:B_1 \to B_2$.

We want to show that there is a bijective function $h: A_1 \times A_2 \to B_1 \times B_2$.

We define $h: A_1 \times A_2 \to B_1 \times B_2$ such that $\langle n,m \rangle \mapsto \langle f(n),g(m) \rangle$

We will show  that $h$ is 1-1.

Let $\langle m_1, n_1 \rangle, \langle m_2, n_2 \rangle \in A_1 \times A_2$ with $h(\langle m_1, n_1 \rangle)=h(\langle m_2, n_2 \rangle) \rightarrow \langle f(n_1),g(m_1) \rangle=\langle f(n_2),g(m_2) \rangle \rightarrow f(n_1))=f(n_2) \wedge g(m_1)=g(m_2) \overset{\text{f,g:} 1-1 }{\rightarrow} m_1=m_2 \wedge n_1=n_2 \rightarrow \langle m_1,n_1 \rangle=\langle m_2,n_2 \rangle$

From the surjectivity of $f,g$ we can conclude that $h$ is surjective.

Could you tell me if it is right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, almost. You need to justify why you can assume $A\cap B=\emptyset$ in the definition of the sum of two cardinals. Other then that, it all seems fine. It is a bit long though. It would be somewhat easier to show the functions you construct are bijective by exhibiting an inverse (constructed from the inverses of the each function you use).

Comment: How could we justify that we can assume that $A \cap B=\varnothing$ in the definition of the sum of two cardinals?
Could we justify it maybe as follows?
$$$$
Let $m=card(D), \ n=card(E)$.
Then $$card(D \times \{0\})=m , \ card(E \times \{1\})=n$$
We set $A=D \times \{0\}$ and $B=E \times \{1\}$ and we see that the sets are dijoint.